# basic function overloading with pointer to parameters giving erros

Tags: c++, function, pointers, struct, overloading

It may be very basic question of function overloading but i'm getting error and hence posting it here. Below is sample code :

// Sample.cpp

```
struct A
{
   struct B
   {

   }b;

   struct C
   {

   }c;
};

set_data(B *b1)
{

}

set_data(C *c1)
{

}

set_data(A *a1)
{

   set_data(a1->c); // this line give error
   set_data(a1->b); // this line give error
}
```

I'm not able to call set_data function with type struct B and struct C; it give error.

Thanks

Comment: I suggest taking a step back and reading an introductory C++ book.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues with your code:
1. The fact that you defined the structs B and C inside struct A causes that to not be accessible as B pr C and you should use the full qualified name A::B and A::C
2. The second issue is that the you are expecting a pointer while passing the actual object, you could fix this by just getting the address of the object

```
    void set_data(A::B *b1)

    void set_data(A::C *c1)

    void set_data(A *a1)
    {
        set_data(&(a1->c));
        set_data(&(a1->b));
    }
```

Now it should work.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Could you post the result of your compile?

Comment: error C2665: 'set_data' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types. Getting this error message. @IonutG

Comment: Are you sure you've added the & in front of (a1->c) and (a1->b)? This would get the address of the member so the methods expecting the pointers would work.

Comment: @lonutG -- yes i have added and still it is giving error... is ti compiling properly at ur end ??

Comment: Yes, it does, but I'm using VC++ compiler, are you using something different?

Comment: @lonutG -- using VS 2012

Comment: In this case it should work. Could you paste again the whole program, after the changes, so I can see if you missed something?

Comment: please see --> entire code is pasted below by user Sumeet

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of mistakes in this code. The line where you are getting compilation error should be:

```
set_data(&a1->c);
set_data(&a1->b);
```

The whole code should be:

```
  struct A
{
    struct B
    {

    }b;

    struct C
    {

    }c;
};

void set_data(A::B *b1)
{

}

void set_data(A::C *c1)
{

}

void set_data(A *a1)
{

    set_data(&a1->c); // this line give error
    set_data(&a1->b); // this line give error
}

void main()
{


}
```

Comment: The other function definitions should produce errors too.

Comment: @Sumeet -- i even tried same answer as above posted.. still error.. error C2665: 'set_data' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types

Comment: @juanchopanza: Yes the function definition produces the errors.

Comment: @user3382670:You have to specify the return type of the function definition and function definition should have name like this:" void set_data(A::B *b1)"

Comment: @Sumeet -  I apologize for not putting the code properly. But even after doing all the corrections .. still issue exists.

Comment: @Sumeet -- please see comments